Why is my subtotal macro running so slowly? It is taking about an hour to run
There are about 4000 rows of data, and macro subtotal takes about an hour to run. Doing the subtotal manually takes about 40 seconds. Can anyone help to check my code?
Below is my code:
Sub XX()

    
    'File upload
    Set wd = ThisWorkbook 'To define the destination workbook
    Set wx = wd.Worksheets("XX") 'To define the destination tab
    Set wy = wd.Worksheets("Data")
    
    'Clear contents & format
    wx.Range("A1", "Z" & 999999).ClearContents
    wx.Range("A1", "Z" & 999999).ClearFormats
    wx.Columns("L:L").RemoveSubtotal
    wy.Range("A1", "Z" & 999999).ClearContents
    wy.Range("A1", "Z" & 999999).ClearFormats

    'Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
    MsgBox "Please Open BB File"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   'Enabling multiple files select
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear
    
    'Only Excel files can be selected
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb; *.csv"
    
    If .Show = True Then
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            'Opening selected file
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
        
    Set ts = ActiveWorkbook 'To define the source workbook
    Set ws = ts.Worksheets(1) 'To define the source tab
        
    
    Dim ws_row As Long
    ws_row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    ws.Range("A1", "S" & ws_row).Copy

    wd.Activate
    wx.Select
    wx.Range("A" & 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    'don't allow any prompt
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'don't save the changes when you close the workbook
    ts.Close savechanges:=False
    
    Next
    End If
    End With
    
    
    'Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
    wy.Select
    MsgBox "Please Open Summary Display File"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   'Enabling multiple files select
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear
    
    'Only Excel files can be selected
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb; *.csv"
    
    If .Show = True Then
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            'Opening selected file
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
        
    Set tp = ActiveWorkbook 'To define the source workbook
    Set wp = tp.Worksheets(1) 'To define the source tab
    
    
    Dim wp_row As Long
    wp_row = wp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    'Filter Column A (Action) to "Check BB Grouping" & "Check Manually" and filter Column C to those with BB No.
    wp.Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter
    wp.Range("A1", "A" & wp_row).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=Check BB Grouping", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Check Manually"
    
    wp.Range("A1", "O" & wp_row).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
        
        
    Dim wp_new_row As Long
    wp_new_row = wp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    wp.Range("A1", "C" & wp_new_row).Copy

    wd.Activate
    wy.Select
    wy.Range("A" & 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    'don't allow any prompt
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'don't save the changes when you close the workbook
    tp.Close savechanges:=False
    
    Next
    End If
    End With
    
    
    'Rearrange Column A (Action)
    wy.Columns("A:A").Cut
    Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    
    'Do text to column for Column A (Orig. Promo No)
    wy.Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    
    
    'Select the whole data and custom sort
    wx.Select
    Dim wx_row As Long
    wx_row = wx.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BB Overlaps").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BB Overlaps").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "F2", "F" & wx_row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BB Overlaps").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "E2", "E" & wx_row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BB Overlaps").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "E2", "E" & wx_row), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BB Overlaps").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("E2", "E" & wx_row), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(204, _
        255, 204)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BB Overlaps").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1", "S" & wx_row)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    

    'Cut Column G (BB No.) and paste it at Column B
    wx.Columns("G:G").Cut
    wx.Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    'Cut Column I (Article Group) and paste it at Column C
    wx.Columns("I:I").Cut
    wx.Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    'Cut Column O (Indv Price) and paste it at Column G
    wx.Columns("O:O").Cut
    wx.Columns("G:G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    'Do text to column for column G (Indv Price)
    wx.Columns("G:G").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("G1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    
    'Convert Column G (Indv Price) to 2 decimal places
    wx.Columns("G:G").NumberFormat = "0.00"

    'Highlight Column G (Indv Price)
    With wx.Columns("G:G").Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    'Insert a new column A
    wx.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    
    'Name new Column A as "Check BB No."
    wx.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Check BB No."

    
    'Vlookup Column C (BB No.) to Summary Display Action
    wx.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],'Summary Display'!C[1]:C[2],2,FALSE)"
    wx.Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2", "A" & wx_row)
    
    'Insert a new column F
    wx.Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    
    'Name new Column F as "Action"
    wx.Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "Action"
    
    'Insert a new column G
    wx.Columns("G:G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    
    'Name new Column G as "New Promo No."
    wx.Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "New Promo No."
    
    'Insert a new column H
    wx.Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    
    'Name new Column H as "New BB No."
    wx.Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "New BB No."
    
    'Insert filter
    wx.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    
    'Autofit Column A to L
    wx.Columns("A:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    'Click on Column L (Article), go to DATA --> Subtotal & Delete Column L
    Set Rng = wx.Range("L1", "L" & wx_row)
    
    Rng.subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlCount, TotalList:=Array(1), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

    wx.Columns("L:L").Delete
    
End Sub

Help me make the macro runs faster, the macro is much slower than doing it manually

Welcome to SO! To make your question more readable, and so that you don't have to write "end sub", I would use triple-backtics to identify the start and end of code blocks: \```

When asking a question about code, the very first tag you add should be for the language that you're using. It helps get the question in front of the users who can answer it, and makes the question visible in searches done by other users. I've edited to add the tag for you and correct the formatting.

@MrDeveloper: End Sub is part of the code. This is Excel VBA. The start of the procedure is indicated by Sub on the first line. End Sub indicates the end of the procedure.

Also, all the time your code is taking is moving cells around and unnecessary use of .Select. We can't help with making that code faster, because it has nothing to do with the subtotal. Moving those cells takes time, and .Select is just a waste of time and CPU cycles, because you don't need to select something to do something with it. Search this site for vba avoid select for some tips on getting rid of it.

There is so much about this code that needs help...  First of all, stop using Copy/Paste and simply set values, Copy/Paste slows things down pretty substantially.  2. Make sure that you have error handling to reset ScreenUpdating and Calculations in the case of an error in your code.  3. Write the values you're working with to an array and work with the array - VASTLY faster.  Your TextToColumns call can be done through an array that will take more code but executes much faster.

thanks everyone for the feedback! however, when i seperated the subtotal in a separate macro, i realized the subtotal is taking a very long time to run. it seems that the macro is doing subtotal row by row that's why it is taking so long. anyone has any idea why?

There is a lot that could be improved in this code:

Remove unnecessary selections. Selecting cells and activating worksheets slows down VBA code. You can directly reference cells and ranges without selecting them. Instead of this

    wx.Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Use this
    wx.Range("A1").PasteSpecial


Turn off screen updating and calculations: Disabling screen updating and automatic recalculation can significantly speed up the macro. Add this at the beginning of your code:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

And add this at the end to restore normal settings:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


Use With blocks more often: Using With blocks helps speed up code by reducing object referencing. For example:

    With wx
        .Columns("G:G").Cut
        .Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End With


Clear large ranges: Instead of clearing the contents and formats of a large range like A1:Z999999, it's more efficient to only clear the used range. Clearing all cells unnecessarily slows down the macro.

    wx.UsedRange.ClearContents
    wx.UsedRange.ClearFormats
    wy.UsedRange.ClearContents
    wy.UsedRange.ClearFormats

The quickest and dirtiest way to speed up your code would be to run it by Ch*tGPT or Pilot and let it improve the most obvious problemsa.
